# How to mock a Scala Seq?

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, powermock, seq

I basically need to test an edge-case where I have a Seq[Foo] with 100 Foo objects. Instead of manually initializing 100 unique Foo objects and adding them to a Seq, is there some functionality of mockito I can use?

What I'm basically trying to do is: 
`val mockSeq = mock(Seq)`
`when(mockSeq).length.thenReturn(100)`

Comment: Why? That's much easier to use a real `Seq` as fixture

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to Scala testing. Could you elaborate?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, try to only mock classes you own

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As cchantep says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60722168/how-to-mock-a-scala-seq#comment107434225_60722168), you're probably better off just creating a Seq and filling it, something like this:

```scala
object Foo
Seq.fill(100)(Foo)
```

This will fill the Seq with 100 Foo objects. I don't see any benefit to using Mockito for something like this.

Read more about it [in the docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/generic/SeqFactory.html#fill[A](n:Int)(elem:=%3EA):CC[A]).